# Integrating node.js with mysql requires my own server?

Tags: mysql, node.js, server

As I've seen, node.js is not natively ready to work with mySQL, so it requires downloading and installing some specific libraries like node-mysql.

The question is: does most servers (like hostgator/godaddy) have support for node.js and node-mysql? Or when I join this area of server-side development I need to setup my own physical server?

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends upon the ISP and their setup, however as a general rule:

Most providers will have separate servers to handle mySQL, and let your node application know the server, port, database name, username and password to connect.

The short of it is: Configuring a system to run a database is very different from configuring a general purpose web server so it is to their advantage to specialize.

This also makes the database available to other applications running on other servers.

However, for my own development and deployment, it is all very very lightweight stuff and I run everything off the same server.

Now -- depending on your needs -- there are some file-based databases which don't require a server at all.

Comment: I understand, but packages like node.js and node-mysql are installed on MY computer. So to my code to run succesfully, I need to run 'here', right? So as far as I know, hosting on a server with MySQL ready is not enough if I'm using other libraries. Do I need to, like, require files in the html file or the .js file?

Comment: Do you need SQL libraries in your HTML or client-side JavaScript files?  Not at all!  You should NEVER, EVER construct SQL client-side... but you *can* pass parameters to an API running on the server and let it query the database for you.  At this point, your question is more about what you are wanting to do ... resolve *that* first, then figure out how to do it.

Comment: I'm planning to do node.js instead of php (or any other language) for the server-side and the website will store a lot of user inputs so I need a database like MySQL managed from phpMyAdmin. Just trying to understand how to merge node.js with MySQL. I saw that I need to download and install an extra library, but I still have my question of 'does webhosting services support node.js and It's libraries?'

Comment: Assuming that the library talks to the same version(s) of mySQL that the hosting provider uses, that should be all you need.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understood what I'm asking or if I'm actually that dumb, but here goes again: I can't run a .js file on a server using JQUERY syntax If I don't provide the library file in the main html file. My question follows the same logic with node.js. I can't setup a local server with the node.js syntax If I don't have it installed on my PC. Since node.js is not a single file like JQUERY, but a whole package that needs to be installed, I don't know how it works when I'm hosting from hostgator for example.

Comment: If I understand your question at this point, your question is: `How do I use the node.js module system?`  I can only give you things to search for ... `NodeJS modules` and `how do I use npm`?